# Display images from a directory and link to video with same name

Tags: php, html

I'm using below code to show all jpg's within a directory.

```
$dirname = "var/www/media/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

In the same directory I have movies with the same name. Example:

```
ls var/www/media
Aliens.mpg
Aliens.jpg
Simsons.avi
Simsons.jpg
```

I need each jpg image to be clickable, linking to the corresponding video file.

Is there an easy way doing that?

Comment: I don't think that you can do it without knowing the extension of the video as you have different extensions for every video.

Comment: But I could lookup the filename and say `filename.(not jpg)` That was my idea but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: It would be easier if you were looping over the videos within the same loop as the image, that way you could grab the extension from each value to verify which are videos / images...

Comment: Do you have specific extensions or you have no idea what are the extensions ? I mean do you have a list of video extensions

Comment: Well, there are many different extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go!

**NOTE** 
1) Make sure file names are same. 
2) You can add more ext file in the variables `$imgExts` and `$vidExts`.

```
<?php
$files = glob("media/*.*");
$vid = NULL;

$imgExts = array("gif", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "tiff", "tif");
$vidExts = array("mp4", "mpg", "avi", "mk4", "ogg", "3gp");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
  $image = $files[$i];
  $urlExt = pathinfo($files[$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  if (in_array($urlExt, $imgExts)) {
    for ($j=0; $j<count($files); $j++) {
      $urlExt2 = pathinfo($files[$j], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      if (in_array($urlExt2, $vidExts)) {
        if (strcmp($urlExt, $urlExt2) == 0) {
          $vid=$files[$j];
        }
      }
    }

    echo '<a href="'.$vid .'"><img src="'.$image .'" />'."<br /></a>";
  }        
}
```

**UPDATE:**

> **It will show the error if any file not found(i.e. if image not found for video or vice versa)**

```
<?php
$x=1;   // initially giving value for x=1 
$files = glob("media/*.*");
$vid=NULL;
$vidf=$files;   //making copy of files array





$imgExts = array("gif", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "tiff", "tif");
$vidExts = array("mp4", "mpg", "avi", "mk4", "ogg", "3gp");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];


$urlExt = pathinfo($files[$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(in_array($urlExt,$imgExts )){
        for($j=0; $j<count($files); $j++){
          $urlExt2 = pathinfo($files[$j], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(in_array($urlExt2,$vidExts )){

                if(strcmp(pathinfo($files[$i], PATHINFO_FILENAME),pathinfo($files[$j], PATHINFO_FILENAME))==0){
                $vid=$files[$j];
                $x=0;   // put the value of x=0 if video for that image found!


        unset($vidf[array_search($vid , $vidf)]); // search & delete video from array with have images


                }
            }
        }





        if($x==0)
        echo '<a href="'.$vid .'"><img src="'.$image .'" />'."<br /></a>";

        else if($x==1){     //check if image have the video
        echo 'Video for Image <b>', pathinfo($image , PATHINFO_FILENAME),'.',pathinfo($image , PATHINFO_EXTENSION),  ' </b>Not Found!<br>';
        $x=0;}
}
}

    foreach ($vidf as $vidf) {    // show let out videos who's images not found

        $urlExt2 = pathinfo($vidf, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(in_array($urlExt2,$vidExts )){
    echo "Image of the Video <b> ",pathinfo($vidf , PATHINFO_FILENAME),'.', pathinfo($vidf , PATHINFO_EXTENSION),'</b> Not found!' ;
    echo '<br>';
            }
} 


?>
```